# How to run it ? SQLlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Maybe my question will be so stupid but I'm really beginner in topic of java/ programming 
I have a tutorial : 

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

And my question is how to run from there an edit of record .

I'm trying with this one but without results:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setAuthor("NEW name");
book.setTitle("new TITLE ");
db.updateBook(list.get(1));
```

Thank's for help !

Comment: db object doesn't have updatebook method and you make the updated object book and send another object to update so it doesn't  edit

Comment: So how to fix it ? ( if I can ask about that kind of help) ?

Comment: yes you can but post your full code , so i can fix the problem

Comment: i can't figure how do mean with this line ? 
  db.UpdateOrder(list.get(order_to_update-1));
and why you don't pass order object to this method

Comment: ok but it's similar way as with delete but in this case we just replace old with new data.
So what do you mean ?

Comment: ok , you can debug your code and check the number returned from update statement if it more than zero or not

Comment: debuging is black magic for me ... how to do it ?

Comment: ok  "i" returned from update is equal to 1

Comment: update statement return the number of rows were effected so , this mean the object is updated successfully  , try to bind data on listview so you can the changed data

Comment: but even in log there is same record as before update

Answer (score 0):

here a good article about debugging , and this skill will help you solving and understand most of problem

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

the Log issue ,

because you log the object that you send to update not the object with the new data so the order object you log is the old object ,

to get the new order data make query after update statement with the order id and you will see the changed data

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
// Updating single book
public int updateBook(Book book, String newTitle, String newAuthor) {

// 1. get reference to writable DB
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

// 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("title", newTitle); // get title 
values.put("author", newAuthor()); // get author

// 3. updating row
int i = db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, //table
        values, // column/value
        KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
        new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) }); //selection args

 // Based on your condition

// 4. close
db.close();

return i;

}
```